# How can I set Grid alignments using numbers?

Tags: options, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

There is an example in the `Alignment` documentation (it also appears in the `Grid` documentation):

```
Grid[{{Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 20], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 30]}, {Graphics[Rectangle[], 
    ImageSize -> 40], Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 50]}}, 
 Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, {Bottom, Top}}]
```

[image]

The `Alignment` documentation indicates that numbers can be used for the alignment. Therefore the example above should be able to be re-written as

```
Grid[{{Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 20], 
   Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 30]}, {Graphics[Rectangle[], 
    ImageSize -> 40], Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> 50]}}, 
 Alignment -> {{1, -1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

However this has no effect:

[image]

So what is the correct way to use numbers for `Alignment`?

Comment: I have assumed that because of the two-dimensional specification accepted by `Grid` (as you use) it does not support the individually two-dimensional alignment specifications.

Comment: The documentation actually only allows for numerical settings using `Alignment->x` or `Alignment->{x,y}`. But I can't get even that to work.

Comment: My interpretation of the documentation is that taking the first code you should be able to substitute 1 for `Right`, -1 for `Left`, -1 for `Bottom` and 1 for `Top` and get the same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can't currently be done -- it is supposed to be possible but doesn't work due to a bug.

To achieve this you need work around such as @Vitaliy's suggestion. Numbered alignment is quite useful so I hope this bug is fixed in the next version.

Comment: Was it confirmed by WRI? Isn't this the proper time then to add [tag:bugs] to the tag list?

Comment: V10.01 and it is still broken. And Mapping with Panes etc. is not a solution, for dynamic content, constant mapping affects performance. The Grid is kind of sick joke, I'm wasting lately a lot of time to do what should be possible with single option.

Comment: @Kuba I couldn't agree more. However designed this stuff has never made layouts themselves. More to the point it seems that there has been a lack of coordination or project management in the design of Grid, Pane, Panel and so on. The result is that you end up just wasting a lot of time on this stuff

Answer (score 17):

It seems that the handling of the `Alignment` option is not consistent for all functions using it. `Panel` for instance seems to support numeric values for this option

```
Manipulate[
 Panel["\[Times]", ImageSize -> {100, 50}, Alignment -> {x, y}],
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -1, 1}
]
```

while with `Grid` this is not supported.
Knowing this, you could check functions you're interested in with something simple like

```
SetAttributes[AlignmentTest, HoldAll];
AlignmentTest[func_] := Row[{
   Manipulate[
    Append[func, Alignment -> {x, y}],
    {x, -1, 1},
    {y, -1, 1}
    ],
   Manipulate[
    Append[func, Alignment -> {x, y}],
    {x, {Left, Center, Right}},
    {y, {Bottom, Center, Top}}
    ]
   }]
```

You see that in many cases numeric values for the `Alignment` option can be used

```
AlignmentTest[
 Button["Click Here", Print[10!], ImageSize -> {100, 100}]]

AlignmentTest[
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, 
  ContentSize -> {500, 500}]]

AlignmentTest[
 Grid[{{"\[Times]", "\[Times]", "\[Times]"}, {"\[Times]", "\[Times]", 
    "\[Times]"}}, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {10, 10}]]

AlignmentTest[Overlay[{Graphics[{Disk[]}], Slider2D[]}, All, 2]]
```

Comment: +1 This `Manipulate` is useful to show the advantage of using numbered `Alignment`. You can align anywhere between -1 and 1 rather than just `Left`, `Center`, `Right` (-1, 0, 1) and `Bottom`, `Center`, `Top` (-1, 0, 1).

Answer (score 15):

The answer given by @halirutan lead me to a thought that we can use Pane[..] as elements of Grid[...] to obtain desired behavior. Panel[...] can work too, but it introduces extra boundaries.

```
Grid@Partition[MapThread[Pane[Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> #1], 
ImageSize -> {60, 60}, Alignment -> #2] &,{{20, 30, 40, 50}, {{1, -1}, 
{-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}}], 2]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Table[Pane["X", ImageSize -> {60, 60}, Alignment -> 
RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]], {n, 2}, {m, 5}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]